# Simple Scrapy crawler won't use item pipeline

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, pipeline

**Background**

I am trying to learn Scrapy by example.

At this point, I have made a CrawlSpider is able to navigate to a page, follow all links, extract  data using CSS selectors and populate items using an item loader.

I am now trying to add an arbitrary pipeline, just so I can get it working.

My issue is that item pipelines for CrawlSpiders appear to need additional definitions than those that use a scrapy.Spider - I cannot find working examples of CrawlSpider pipelines.

**What my code actually does**

Starts at the wikipedia page for lexus and follows all other wikipedia pages that link from it.
It then extracts the title of each page, and headings from the first table. These are stored in items, which are then printed to a .txt document.

**lexuswikicrawl.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from wikicars.items import WikiItem

#Global variables
pages = {}
failed_pages = 1
filename = 'wiki.txt'



class GenSpiderCrawl(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'lexuswikicrawl'

    #Start at the lexus wikipedia page, and only follow the wikipedia links
    allowed_domains = ['wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexus']

    #There are no specific rules specified below, therefore all links will be followed              
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback = 'parse_page'),)

    #Define what selectors to crawl
    def parse_page(self, response): 
        global pages
        global failed_pages

        #Try and capture the page title using CSS selector
        #If not, keep count of the amount of failed selectors
        try:
            pagename = (response.css('div#content.mw-body > h1#firstHeading::text').extract())[0]
        except:
            pagename = ('Failed pagename: '+ str(failed_pages))
            failed_pages += 1


        # Capture table categories that fall under the CSS selector for regular text items
        tabcat = response.css('#mw-content-text > div > table.infobox.vcard > tbody > tr > th::text').extract() 
        # Capture tale categories that fall under CSS selector for text with hyperlinks
        for i in range(20):
            tabcatlink1 = response.css('#mw-content-text > div > table.infobox.vcard > tbody > tr:nth-child('+str(i)+') > th > a::text').extract()
            tabcatlink2 = response.css('#mw-content-text > div > table.infobox.vcard > tbody > tr:nth-child('+str(i)+') > th > div > a::text').extract()
            if len(tabcatlink1) > 0:
                tabcat.append(tabcatlink1)
            else:
                pass
            if len(tabcatlink2) > 0:
                tabcat.append(tabcatlink2)
            else: 
                continue

        #Load 'pagename' and 'categories' into a new item

        page_loader = ItemLoader(item=WikiItem(), selector = tabcat)

        page_loader.add_value('title', pagename)
        page_loader.add_value('categories', tabcat)

        #Store the items in an overarching dictionary structure
        pages[pagename] = page_loader.load_item()

        #Try and print the results to a text document
        try:
            with open(filename, 'a+') as f:
                f.write('Page Name:'   + str(pages[pagename]['title'])+ '\n')
        except: 
            with open(filename, 'a+') as f:
                f.write('Page name error'+ '\n')
        try:
            with open(filename, 'a+') as f:
                f.write('Categories:'  + str(pages[pagename]['categories'])+ '\n')
        except:
            with open(filename, 'a+') as f:
                f.write('Table Category data not available'  + '\n')
```

**items.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose

def convert_categories(categories):
    categories = (str(categories).upper().strip('[]'))
    return categories

def convert_title(title):
    title = title.upper()
    return title

class WikiItem(scrapy.Item):

    categories = scrapy.Field(
                              input_processor = MapCompose(convert_categories)
                              )

    title      = scrapy.Field(
                              input_processor = MapCompose(convert_title)
```

**pipelines.py**

This is where I suspect trouble is caused. My current thinking is that I need something more than just process_item() to get my Pipeline to run. I have tried all I can to rearrange the examples from: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html.

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class PipelineCheck(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        print('I am a pipeline this is an item:' + str(item) + '\n')
```

***settings.py***

I have declared my pipeline and its priority. I have also declared a generic user agent. Is there an additional variable i need to set?

```
BOT_NAME = 'wikicars'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['wikicars.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'wikicars.spiders'

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'wikicars.pipelines.PipelineCheck': 100,
}
```

Comment: Your `from_crawler` method is the issue, but I can't suggest a fix since I'm not sure what you're trying to do with it

Comment: Thanks for the response - the aim of my pipeline is simply:
print('I am a pipeline this is an item:' + str(item) + '\n')
All I want to be able to do is to print something to the console that comes from a pipeline. At this point, I do not mind what it is.

If i can do this without from_crawler method, then great. However, if i need from_crawler in there, can you suggest the correct way to impliment it?

Comment: You only need to define methods you want to change, so if you don't need to use a method, don't define it.

Comment: That's what I thought at the start. But this does not work:
`class PipelineCheck(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        print('I am a pipeline this is an item:' + str(item) + '\n')`

Comment: I have edited the post for clarity. The version that does not contain a 'from_crawler' method will not run a pipeline. My issue is that I cannot get a pipeline to run from a crawler spider. I don't care what the pipeline does at this moment.

Comment: The pipeline is activated, but you're not yielding any items in your spider, so nothing is passing through the pipeline.

Comment: stranac, thanks - this was the nugget of info that I needed! With a yield statement, I now have working pipelines.